# Complex OrderBy using multiple columns

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by, laravel-5.7, laravel-query-builder

I have a football events table that shows events based on `minute` and `extra_minute`. For example:

```
 id |    type    | minute | extra_minute  |  reason
 1  | yellowcard |   45   | null          |   null
 2  | yellowcard |   45   |  1            |   null
 3  |   period   |   45   | null          |    HT
 4  |    goal    |   45   |  2            |   null
 5  |    goal    |   46   |  2            |   null    // this is second half
 6  |   period   |   90   | null          |    FT
 7  |    goal    |   90   |  2            |   null
```

The order should be

```
yellowcard (45)
yellowcard (45+1)
   goal    (45+2)
    HT
   goal    (46)
   goal    (90+2)
    FT
```

I tried a relationship query in Match like

```
public function events() {
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class)->orderBy('minute', 'asc')
                                       ->orderBy('extra_minute', 'asc');
}
```

But this results in

```
    HT
yellowcard (45)
yellowcard (45+1)
   goal    (45+2)
   ...
```

What is the way of sorting the desired style with Laravel Query Builder? *I know why my query builder is not working but I couldn't come up with something to achieve what I want*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->orderByRaw('type = ? asc', 'period')` is the way to do it.

```
return $this->hasMany(Event::class)
            ->orderBy('minute', 'asc')
            ->orderByRaw('type = ? asc', 'period')
            ->orderBy('et_minute', 'asc');
```